# jQuery Deferred promise logic assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am trying to figure out the logic required for promises to work.  My (simplified) example does this:

```
var FLEX = FLEX || {};
FLEX.Core = {
__networkIdToken: '',
__r: "",
Init: function() {          
    var deferred = $.Deferred();        
    FLEX.Core.Config();
    FLEX.Core.RegisterHandlers();
    FLEX.Core.Execute();    
},

Config: function() {
    yam.config({
        debug: true,
        appId: FLEX_YAMMER_CONFIGID
    }); 
},

RegisterHandlers: function() {
    $(FLEX_YAMMER_LOGINBUTTON).on('click', function(){
        FLEX.Core.Login();
    });
},

Execute: function() {
    //Get Network Token from local storage (if exists)
    __networkIdToken = localStorage.getItem(FLEX_YAMMER_AUTHTOKEN);
    if(__networkIdToken != null)
    {       
        //If network token is set then set Auth Token and continue
        yam.platform.setAuthToken(__networkIdToken);    

        //RETURN NEEDS TO HAPPEN HERE

    }
    else
    {
        //If no Network Token set, display login panel to enable login
        FLEX.Core.ShowLoginPanel(false);
    }   
},

ShowLoginPanel: function (_loggedIn) {
    if (_loggedIn) {
        $(FLEX_YAMMER_LOGINPANEL).hide();
    } else {
        $(FLEX_YAMMER_LOGINPANEL).show();
    }   
}
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    FLEX.Core.Init().done(testFunction);
    function testFunction()
    {
        alert('Test');
    }
});
```

The Call from document ready needs to check if the user is logged in. (execute function).  If the local storage object (which sets __networkIdToken) is empty then it will show the login panel and this has independent button logic (removed from example).  If there IS a network id then i would like a promise to be returned here...removed the need to any async logic for login.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just `return FLEX.Login()`? (Maybe also consider returning `__r.promise()` from `Login()`.)

Comment: because in my actual code (ive simplified for here) after init i have about 2-3 chained functions that do various things before the login function has been done...  ive ammended the code above to make clearer

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     __r = $.Deferred();
>     […]
>     return __r;
> ```

`__r` is a property of your object, but here you're assigning to a global variable! Change to

```
    this.__r = …
    […]
    return this.__r;
```

> ```
>     FLEX.Login();
> }
> ```

You're not returning anything from the `INIT` method on which the `.done()` could be called. (Also, you're missing `.Core` in the access of `.Login`) Change it to

```
    return this.Login();
}
```

---

Design Pattern improvement: Every function that does any asynchronous tasks should create an Deferred itself, and `return` a Promise for it.

> with a final function which i was hoping to return the deferred object

No, that's not how promises work. The *initial* function handles the deferred and returns the promise, the "final" (asynchronous callback) function only *resolves* the deferred - which might trigger other processes (the "final" is local to one async task, not "final" handler in a chain of tasks).

```
var FLEX = FLEX || {};
FLEX.Core = {
    __networkIdToken: '',
    __r: null,
    Init: function() {
        // some pseudo-action that might resemble your process
        // implemented with promises
        this.__r = FLEX.getAuthToken().catch(function(noAuthTokenError) {
            showLoginForm();
            return getNextFormSubmission().then(function(credentials) {
                return serverRequest(credentials).then(function (token) {
                    hideLoginForm();
                    return token;
                }, function(authError) {
                    // try again? Get next form submission...
                });
            });
        }).then(function(token) {
            yam.platform.setAuthToken(token);
        });
        return this.__r;
    },
    Login: function () {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        //Asynchronous Login Code Goes here, callback {
            d.resolve();
            // or
            d.reject();
        // }
        return d.promise();
    }
    // similarly for the other async tasks
}
```

> If there IS a network id then i would like a promise to be returned here...removed the need to any async logic for login

You *always* want to return a promise, even if the result is synchronously available. The logic to handle a maybe-async login must be asynchronous anyway. In your case, it might look like

```
FLEX.getAuthToken /* as used above */ = function() {
    var __networkIdToken = localStorage.getItem(FLEX_YAMMER_AUTHTOKEN);
    if (__networkIdToken != null)
        return $.when(__networkIdToken);
    else
        return $.Deferred().reject(); // the rejection will be handled by the .catch
        // or maybe try another storage?
}
```

Comment: If you check my amended code example does this change the above?

Comment: The issues seem to be the same. Not sure what `Complete` does. Maybe you shouldn't have removed all the async code.

Comment: Basically...my (actual) code initiates then performs a check or login to a 3rd party system (using async calls).  The reason for the "promise" is so that i can run the code and wait for it to check if logged in and return or if not logged in then return.  Please DO NOT take the code above literally..i have simplified it from 150 lines.  The login performs about 2-3 separate async callbacks to different services which is again why the login function is i believe too simple in your example.

Comment: Im happy to share code independently i am just unable to share in this context (public on net)

Comment: Try to make each of the separate async calls with their callbacks an independent promise. Then chain them in the Login function. I see that you've simplified the code a lot, but I would need a little less simplification.

Comment: can you tweet me on @ics_chris an email i can send you my current full code?

Comment: No, please just expand that `FLEX.Complete` a little. It is called in the callback of the first login step? What does it do, another async step? Where do you resolve the `__r` deferred?

Comment: I have added the js fiddle code (almost my full code)...therefore shared the contained example already...

Comment: updated again jsfiddle to include missing constants  http://jsfiddle.net/HdXUn/2/

Comment: I am aware this is not a DEBUG MY CODE service...if it was i would pay someone..If i knew the answer i wouldn't be here..I dont know the way to expand it without showing the full code...im not asking for a re-write, im trying to get a promise working (like the original question) and the example shows the async's.  I can see the obvious "tone" of your responses but be aware, if i was doing a "debug my code" answer then i would have pasted the whole code in the original answer..i was specifically trying NOT to do this!

Comment: @user257503 I've reverted the downvote for an upvote on the question, and voted to reopen it, thanks for taking the time to fix your question.

Comment: Im guessing because of all of the "faff" the momentum on this has been lost...shame!